Looping if statement
I want to loop through an array with an if statement and only after it has looped through the entire array execute the else.
This is how i have my code now
for index, nameList in enumerate(checkedName)
    if record["first_name"] == nameList["first_name"] and record["last_name"] == nameList["last_name"]:
        print("Match name")
    else:
        print("No match name")
        checkedName.append({"id" : record["id"], "first_name" : record["first_name"], "last_name" : record["last_name"]})

But i would like it to be more like this:
for index, nameList in enumerate(checkedName) if record["first_name"] == nameList["first_name"] and record["last_name"] == nameList["last_name"]:
    print("Match name")
else:
    print("No match name")
    checkedName.append({"id" : record["id"], "first_name" : record["first_name"], "last_name" : record["last_name"]})

But i have no idea how to do this in a not so messy way i have an idea but i feel like i could do this shorter

why you using enumerate() you weren't using the index in your comparisons?

Do you use the same sequence for iterating (for … in checkedName) and appending within the loop (checkedName.append(…)) on purpose? That's hard to read/understand in the best case and prone to errors in the worst case.

@Bhargav i was using enumrate because i think i will use it later to delete the dublicate record

What should checkedName look like before and after running this code in the two cases where record["first_name"] == nameList["first_name"] ...  is True and when it is False?

@simon im looking for duplicate records and then after im gonna merge them into one.
Its a list of contact info so the emails and telephone numbers will be merged

checkedName is just temporarily used to store data for this loop its just an empty array.
Im making a function to check for duplicate names and then merge the records together

Using any() is more pythonic and  readable...Logic is like check if any record in the list matches your conditions
if any(record["first_name"] == nameList["first_name"] and 
       record["last_name"] == nameList["last_name"] 
       for nameList in checkedName):
    print("Match name")
else:
    print("No match name")
    checkedName.append({
        "id": record["id"], 
        "first_name": record["first_name"], 
        "last_name": record["last_name"]
    })


You could use for/else:
for nameList in checkedName:
    if record["first_name"] == nameList["first_name"] and record["last_name"] == nameList["last_name"]:
        print("Match found")
        break
else:
    print("No match name")
    checkedName.append({"id" : record["id"], "first_name" : record["first_name"], "last_name" : record["last_name"]})

The else branch will execute after the last loop iteration unless break is encountered prior.
